# Android how to print sqlite data inside normal string array?

Tags: android, sqlite

hello every one i face this  problem and iam too weak in DB
i wrote this code to fill the database
and now i want to copy  the data inside an array to print it out inside arrayadapter
coz iam using tabactivity and this is the best solution i found

```
public void insertIntoTable(){
        try{
            mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(ID, NAME) VALUES("+Phno.getText()+",'"+PName.getText()+"')"); 

            mydb.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in inserting into table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
```

and this is how i want to print it out

```
 mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        Cursor allrows  = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE, null);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Iwant to put the cursor data here" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will work for you

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        Cursor allrows  = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE, null);
allrows.moveFirst()
while(allrows.moveToNext()){ 
      String name= allrows.getString(allrows.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
      values.add(name); 
}
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thank you for your response but there is an error that says "change type of name to int"

Comment: thank you very very much the error was from this line allrows.getString(getColumnIndex("NAME"))

but i want to ask you something how can i refresh the list by button or any thing if i add new row

Comment: you can just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); where you want refresh it

Comment: and one more thing there was an error in my code  i edited now.. it should be allrows.getColumnIndex("NAME"); instead of getColumnIndex("NAME");

Comment: glad that it helped ..happy codin:)

Comment: just the last question how can i print the number and the name in organized way in the same line
i tried this code but it's not organized
values.add(name+"\t"+number);

Comment: values.add(name+"\t"+number); loooks okay.. i think "\t" is not working .. give some space instead..But You can do this more efficiently by placing name left indent and number to right indent for that you need to write custom listview instead of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1.

Comment: I think "moveFirst" needs to be "moveToFirst", otherwise great answer thanks!